# Would it be possible to add more images at a certain checkpoint and resume training from that checkpoint?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am evaluating tensorflow object detection API.
I have looked at a few articles that I found on the Internet and I am able to train the model and evaluate object detection successfully.

When I started training, there were about 100 images that are labeled. 
I want to add two or three news images to TFrecord.
After adding those images, should I delete my model_output directory and start train.py or can I do that on top of existing checkpoints?

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow supports restoring the status from a checkpoint as you can see from the official documentation:

https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model

```
# Create some variables.
v1 = tf.get_variable("v1", shape=[3])
v2 = tf.get_variable("v2", shape=[5])

# Add ops to save and restore all the variables.
saver = tf.train.Saver()

# Later, launch the model, use the saver to restore variables from disk, and
# do some work with the model.
with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Restore variables from disk.
  saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
  print("Model restored.")
  # Check the values of the variables
  print("v1 : %s" % v1.eval())
  print("v2 : %s" % v2.eval())
```

If you are not adding or deleting classes you don't need to restart your model. However pay attention to whether the learning rate has changed during your previous training. If your scheduler decreases the learning rate aggressively, you might not be able to learn the new images due to the learning rate being too small.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a new `train.record` file containing the new images that wish to train on and can use the previous saved checkpoint to resume training. All you need to do is to change the `input_path` of the `tf_record_input_reader` to point to the new `train.record` file and the `fine_tune_checkpoint` to something like `<path>/model.ckpt-XXX` instead of the original checkpoint used when you first started training.

Hope you found this helpful. Let me know in case you face any issues